# Return string from lambda expression stream().filter()

Tags: java, lambda

I have something like this and I want to get a String as a result

```
    List<Profile> profile;
    String result = profile
                       .stream()
                       .filter(pro -> pro.getLastName().equals("test"))
                       .flatMap(pro -> pro.getCategory())
```

getCategory() should return an string but not sure what I have to use to return a string, I tried several things but any worked

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What if there is more than one element in the stream?

Comment: Why are you calling `flatMap()`?

Comment: Yes, actually after .filter() y used findFirst()

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.joining());`... ?

Comment: are you actually just trying to get the category of the profile with last name "test"? Or are you trying to collect all of the categories for all profiles with last name "test" into a single string?

Comment: If you only have one person with the last name of 'test', use `findFirst`

Comment: the first one trying to get the category of the profile with last name "test"

Answer (score 10):

```
List<Profile> profile;
String result = profile.stream()
                       .filter(pro -> pro.getLastName().equals("test"))
                       .map(pro -> pro.getCategory())
                       .findFirst()
                       .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few solutions depending on what you're trying to do. If you have a single profile you're targeting that you want to get the category of, you can use a [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) or [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) to get the profile you want and then get the category from the resulting `Optional`.

```
Optional<String> result = profile.stream()
                                .filter(pro -> pro.getLastName().equals("test"))
                                .map(Profile::getCategory)
                                .findFirst(); // returns an Optional
```

Note that `findFirst` returns an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). It handles the possibility that you don't actually have any that meet your criteria in a way that you can handle gracefully.

Alternatively, if you're trying to concatenate the categories of all profiles with last name of "test", then you can use a `.collect(Collectors.joining())` to accumulate a String.

```
List<Profile> profile; // contains multiple profiles with last name of "test", potentially
String result = profile.stream()
                       .filter( pro -> pro.getLastName().equals("test"))
                       .map(Profile::getCategory)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // results in a comma-separated list
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the first one with Optional and it worked, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use on your stream method collect(Collectors.joining()) which will collect your Stream  as String.
Under the hood it will use StringJoiner class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Collectors class java doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--

I think it will help you